# If statement works weird javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```js
var pass = 'budi baj baj bastajpan';
var vpass = '';
var password = document.querySelector('#password-field');

function getPassword() {
    vpass = Array.from(pass);
    for (i = 0; i < vpass.length; i++) {
        if (vpass[i] === ' ') {
            vpass[i] = ' ';
        } else {
            vpass[i] = '_';
        }
    }
    password.innerHTML = vpass;
    addLetters();
}

var lettersField = document.querySelector('#letters');

var alfabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function addLetters() {
    var letters = '';
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        letters = letters + '<span class="letter" id="let' + i + '" onclick="checkLetter(' + i + ')">' + alfabet[i] + '</span>';
    }
    lettersField.innerHTML = letters;
}

function checkLetter(nr) {
    passArr = Array.from(pass);
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        if (passArr[i] == alfabet[nr]) {
            document.querySelector("#let" + nr).style.background = "green";
            vpass[i] = alfabet[nr];
            password.innerHTML = vpass;
        } else {
            document.querySelector("#let" + nr).style.background = "red";
        }
    }
}


window.onload = getPassword;

/*
So, basically i know i probably made ton of mistakes but can u explain me why does this two rows: 
vpass[i] = alfabet[nr];
password.innerHTML = vpass;
Work exactly as i want that means it only changes the password when i click on right letter.

But background changes to red whatever letter i click. (every style i put to ELSE work on every letter but styles in IF work fine.
*/
```

```css
#game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 3px solid green;
}

#password-field {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: dimgray;
    color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#status {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    background: lightgray;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#letters {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    background: lightgray;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: -300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.letter {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.letter:hover {
    background: lightblue;
    border-color: blue;
    transition: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ramphastos Toco</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div id="game">
        <div id="password-field"></div>
        <div id="status"></div>
        <div id="letters"></div>
    </div>
        
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
var pass = 'budi baj baj bastajpan';
var vpass = '';
var password = document.querySelector('#password-field');

function getPassword() {
    vpass = Array.from(pass);
    for (i = 0; i < vpass.length; i++) {
        if (vpass[i] === ' ') {
            vpass[i] = ' ';
        } else {
            vpass[i] = '_';
}
}
password.innerHTML = vpass;
}

var lettersField = document.querySelector('#letters');

var alfabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function addLetters() {
    var letters = '';
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
letters = letters + '<span class="letter" id="let' + i + '" onclick="checkLetter(' + i + ')">' + alfabet[i] + '</span>';
}
lettersField.innerHTML = letters;
}

function checkLetter(nr) {
  passArr = Array.from(pass);
  for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    if (passArr[i] === alfabet[nr]) {
      document.querySelector("#let" + nr).style.background = "green";
      vpass[i] = alfabet[nr];
      password.innerHTML = vpass;
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#let" + nr).style.background = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

Can u explain me why does this two rows:

```
vpass[i] = alfabet[nr];
password.innerHTML = vpass;
```

Work exactly as i want that means it only changes the password when i click on right letter.

But background changes to red whatever letter i click. (every style i put to ELSE work on every letter but styles in IF work fine).

Stackoverflow wants me to put some more details if i want to add snippet so i will just put some text cuz i dont know what more can i really say about...

Comment: What's "pass"? what's "alfabet"?  You have not posted enough code for anybody to really understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Maybe its a problem of the "==="? 3 equals will also compare the type of Object, so if "vpass[i]" and "alphabet[nr]" do not extend from the same object, this will always fail.

Comment: Ok, i will edit it

Comment: Ok, another thing: This is a for cycle in all the letters if I'm understanding correctly.
You only change the password if the letter is correct, but you change the background if its correct or incorrect. What this means is: The password will always change, because you will always match at least one letter, and the background will always be the color (green/red) of then last letter evaluated (probably "z")

Comment: That would be perfect if you could put your issue inside a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: I added the rest of the code, 3 and 2 equals make no difference.

Comment: added snippet as u wished

Comment: Can you break all that code down into the pieces that are really needed? If this is a question of pure HTML, all that CSS looks unnecessary to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you edited your question a bit further, it was hard to understand.

Your problem is exacly the "for" loop.
You iterate through every letter of the password, so:

```
else {
  document.querySelector("#let" + nr).style.background = "red";
}
```

Will always be executed for all the letters of the alphabet that don't match the letter of the password you're evaluating. And this will override any previously made match!

**So, if the current letter you're evaluating is not a "z", the background will always be red!**

My correction suggestion:

```
function checkLetter(nr) {
    let flag=0;
    passArr = Array.from(pass);
      for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        if (passArr[i] === alfabet[nr]) {
          document.querySelector("#let" + nr).style.background = "green";
          flag=1; //if the letter is found, stop checking for the background
          vpass[i] = alfabet[nr];
          password.innerHTML = vpass;
        } else {
          if(flag==0)
             document.querySelector("#let" + nr).style.background = "red";
        }
      }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Now the code uses a flag, to stop changing the background as soon as a letter is found. So the cycle runs the full way, but on the first letter found it switches the color to green. Otherwise, it will always be red.

Comment: Unfortunately this not fixed it completely cuz for example if i click "A" it only changes first letter "A" in the password and ends the loop

Comment: Oh, yeah! Give me a sec, I'll post you another edit.

Comment: I think the edit should work. Let me know if you need anything else. :)